# Attempt to write to read-only property: Indexes. Declaring type: Sitecore.Data.Database

Tags: indexing, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I just finished the upgrade of a sitecore site from 6.6 to 7.0 and after dealing with a lot of lucene code changes (few methods were Deprecated), now i can build my code with no errors. 
But Now i am having this issue:

> Attempt to write to read-only property: Indexes. Declaring type:
>   Sitecore.Data.Database
>   [image]
>   It looks like an indexing issue. i looked online but couldn't find a way to fix this specific issue.

Comment: I assume you were using the old [Sitecore Search Contrib](http://sitecorian.github.io/SitecoreSearchContrib/) module? Did you remove this code and move across to using `ContentSearch` API? Does your indexes folder have the correct permissions set for your IIS user?

Comment: @jammykam With the upgrade to 7 , i think i am using ContentSearch. but i am not sure how to remove the code associated with the old module. Also i checked the IIS permissions and they are right.
Any other suggestions, this is my first ever sitecore upgrade

Comment: It should just be `scSearchContrib.Crawler.config` and `scSearchContrib.Searcher.dll` but depends on how much you integrated. Are you able to log into the Sitecore backend? If so go to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and check the value of sc.variable `dataFolder` (or check through your configs) and then make sure the indexes folder within that has the correct write permissions. Failing that, I would be tempted to install a clean version of Sitecore 7, attach your existing databases to that install, make sure you can log in etc and then deploy your codebase over this new instal.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by deleting my custom searching index file in the `\App_Config\Include` folder and perform  re indexing